# uwsgi and apache2 issue

Tags: apache, uwsgi

I'm having trouble with setting up uwsgi behind apache2.
Here's my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.20 (Ubuntu)

$ uwsgi --version
2.0.14

$ cat /etc/init/uwsgi.conf 
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log

$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

With

```
$ cat ~/myapp/wsgi.py
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ["<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"]
```

and

```
$ cd ~/myapp
$ uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8081 --protocol=http -w wsgi
```

i can browse to http://example.com:8081 and see the "Hello there!" test page. So, I'm assuming uwsgi is working correctly. However, I want to put uwsgi behind apache2, but whenenver I try

```
$ a2enmod uwsgi
```

and restart apache2 I get an error that I can't make sense of:

```
$ service apache2 restart
* Restarting Apache httpd web server apache2                    [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/uwsgi.load:
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_uwsgi.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_uwsgi.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have searched for hours but I can't find aynthing that helped me with this..

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: Oh, and I couldn't find any relevant information in the apache error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, here's how i got it to work:

Instead of using the uwsgi_mod, i simply proxied everything in my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

The uwsgi command would run with `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` where `uwsgi.ini` would contain the following lines

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = path/to/my/project
http-socket = :8081
module = wsgi:application
...
```

That way i don't need to run the uwsgi_mod and everything works. Hopefully that helps anyone, someday.